# understanding php code and Call javascript function once in 24hours

Tags: javascript, php

I came accross following code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var timeoutId;
        var intervalId;

        function doIt(){
            $("#main").load("refresh.php");
        }
        $(document).ready(function(){
            timeoutId = setTimeout(function(){
                doIt();
                intervalId = setInterval(function(){
                    doIt();
                }, 5000); //Request the doIt() method every 5ms.
            }, 3000); //Delay calculated on the server to trigger the function at the appropriate time
        }); 
    </script>
```

1. Rather then calling every 5 second  is there any way to call it at 8am everyday in the morning?
2. `$("#main").load("refresh.php");` will load the result from refresh.php page on div with id main right?

Comment: Sounds like a cron job task i think

Comment: Javascript gets executed inside a browser. Sounds weird when you want something to execute on a browser everyday at 8 am!

Comment: @Thrustmaster: I am showing updated data on user's profile page. when ever user login he can see last 1 hour updated record on the page

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to keep the browser up all the time, because `javascript` is a client side language.

Instead use **Cron Job**, to schedule tasks.

Comment: I am showing updated data on user's profile page. when ever user login he can see last 1 hour updated record on the page

Comment: So set up a Cron Job with a frequency of a day i.e. daily and give it address of the update page.

Comment: Cron Job will simply hit that url after the said time.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to call it every morning at 8 AM.

If the browser is open at 8 AM, just make a call to server to get the latest data.

You can use the `getHours()` method of date object and check the time. At 8 AM, refresh the data.